# How to detect that Safari is in reader mode?

Tags: javascript, ios, macos, safari

I would like to be able from Javascript to be notified when Safari is in `reader` mode. Is there an event fired by the browser or a flag set?

The question relates to iPhone, iPad and OSX.

Answer (score 0):

it's in the `location.protocol`.

on safari it is:
`safari-reader:`

Firefox:
`about:`

Not sure what it is on chrome but you get the point.