# Javascript event listener on reader view mode activation

Tags: javascript, safari

Is there a way for me to track or listen to an event if user activates readermode view of my website?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11132321/6568620

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect that Safari is in reader mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132321/how-to-detect-that-safari-is-in-reader-mode)